# How to create user in salesforce using Web/REST API from c#?

Tags: c#, rest, salesforce

I am working on a WCF service where I need to sync the users from Windows Active Directory to a Salesforce account. I don't want to use any 3rd party tool or service, but want to develop a new one. I tried to use Partner WSDL provided by salesforce, but couldn't get how I can utilize it to create a new user in salesforce. Please give me some pointer on how I can utilize Web/REST API to create a new user in salesforce. Any sample code or link which can explain it.

Comment: By the way you can ask Salesforce questions directly on [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 4):

For Salesforce's REST API you can use  [SalesforceSharp](https://github.com/giacomelli/SalesforceSharp).

The sample code below will create an user on your Salesforce account:

```
var client = new SalesforceClient();
var authenticationFlow = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFlow
(clientId, clientSecret, username, password);

client.Authenticate (authenticationFlow);

var user = new 
{
    Username = "email@domain.com",
    Alias =  "userAlias",
    // The ID of the user profile (Standard User, System Administrator, etc).
    ProfileId = "00ei000000143vq", 
    Email = "email@domain.com",
    EmailEncodingKey = "ISO-8859-1",
    LastName = "lastname",
    LanguageLocaleKey = "pt_BR",
    LocaleSidKey = "pt_BR",
    TimeZoneSidKey = "America/Sao_Paulo"
};

var id = client.Create ("User", user);
```

Comment: For profileID, where did you get 00ei000000143vq? I am trying to create a user and not sure where to generate that at...